# Using separators between the grok expressions

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have to write a grok expression for the given line :

```
2019-11-14 17:29:20 fqm.kfa::(1087651)
```

I am able to write grok for the part of line before `::` as follows :

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?\s*%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}
```

and it works perfectly fine. However when I try to combine the part of the line after `::`, it shows `No matches`

```
%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})?\s*%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}::(%{INT:num})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would suggest instead of breaking down the date into many fields like day, hour, minute, second, etc. (which usually you don't need them separately) to use the `TIMESTAMP_ISO8601` data type.

The second part is problematic not because of the "::" but because of the `(` and `)`. these special characters used by regex. In order to use them you will have to escape them like this: `\(` and `\)`.

Like this:

```
^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:event_timestamp}%{SPACE}%{WORD:word1}.%{WORD:word2}::\(%{NUMBER:num:int}\)$
```

Notice I have also change the num data type to NUMBER:num:int that will cause ES to treat this data as integer enabling you later to use filters like bigger/smaller than.